# Refresh button on an Access form

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an access form which displays lot of information regarding number of records in different queries using Dcount, Dmax, Dmin, Dcount functions. This count is displayed within a selected Date Range. So I have a start date and an end date text boxes. When I enter the start date and end date the info is not displayed automatically but when I use Refresh all button from the Quick access tool bar it works.

Therefore I created a button using Refresh method from the Macro. Although when I use this button it gives me an error

```
The command or action 'Refresh' isn't available now
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Code Builder method?

`Private Sub RefreshCmd1_Click()
    Me.Refresh
End Sub`

Comment: Did this answer your question? I'm wanting to make sure that was helpful in some way