# Unable to replicate Refresh All quick access toolbar button in form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with several subforms whose content is edited in separate forms, opened by command buttons.

When the data in those forms is updated, and the extra forms closed, naturally the main form needs to be refreshed before those changes can be seen. Clicking the Refresh All quick access toolbar button achieves this perfectly.

So I made a macro for the "got focus" event on the main form to refresh it, but it does nothing. I tried repaint and requery as well, applying the latter specifically to the subforms in question, and ran them out of vba instead of an access interface built macro too, none of these seem to solve the problem.

vba coding:

```
Private Sub Form_GotFocus()

Screen.ActiveForm.Requery
Screen.ActiveForm.Repaint
Screen.ActiveForm.Refresh
Me.sfmContact.Requery
Me.frmCustCert.Requery
Me.frmCustReq.Requery

End Sub
```

Annoying thing is that if I put this (or even just the macro or `Screen.ActiveForm.Refresh`) in the on click event of one of the controls it works fine. Just can't seem to make it work in any automatic events that don't require thought or clicks from the end user.

This question is sort of a dupe of [Refresh button on an Access form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586631/refresh-button-on-an-access-form) but that question is over a year old, and has no accepted answer. So I've expanded on it.

Comment: Is it even running the code in GotFocus event? You might want to try the Form_Activate event instead

Comment: My guess is that it's not running it, but I don't know why.
I got mixed up between OnActivate and OnLoad, which is why I didn't try that option. That works and solves the problem, but why wouldn't GotFocus fire? Surely the main form lost focus when another form got it for updating, and then it got it back again when the other form closed/anything in the main form was selected...

Comment: Glad you got it working for you. Following VBA event progression is one of life's unpleasant tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mentioned in your comment there is correct:

> My guess is that it's not running it, but I don't know why. I got mixed up between OnActivate and OnLoad, which is why I didn't try that option. That works and solves the problem, but why wouldn't GotFocus fire? Surely the main form lost focus when another form got it for updating, and then it got it back again when the other form closed/anything in the main form was selected...

To avoid this type of error in the future, it may be prudent to specifically name the form in your code instead of using the "Me." command, as that only works for current focus. For instance:

```
Me.sfmContact.Requery > Forms![FormName].sfmContact.Requery
```

Alternatively, you could just set the focus to the form in question before that sort of coding.

```
Forms![FormName].SetFocus
```

Comment: I think I only just processed what you mean:
Are you saying that the *reason* `GotFocus` wasn't doing anything wasn't because it wasn't firing, but was because it fires when the form (or whatever object) gets the focus *but before it activates*? So both `ActiveForm` and `Me.` refer to something that *is active* which happens *after* the thing *gets focus*? And therefore if I changed it to bang notation, explicitly referencing the form/form controls it would still work on the `GotFocus` event?

Comment: Focus is not a natural thing for a form. In other words, when it opens the `GotFocus` command will never trigger because a form cannot recieve a `GotFocus` event. This type of trigger is usually used for sub-forms only. Usually, in this type of scenario you would either use a `OnLoad` (if you want the event to trigger when the form is first opened) or a secondary action (such as a button press, or a check box being activated, etc.). Technically a form *can* recieve focus in a specific situation where the all visible controls on a form are disabled, or there are no controls on the form.